# PHP normalization of URL to identical form

Tags: php, url

I want to check URLs against a list to make choices about processing (this will be looking at datastreams, not as a router in an application) but HTTP makes it very easy to represent the *same* URL in lots of different ways, e.g. (adapted from rfc 2616):

```
http://example.com/~smith/home.html
http://example.com:80/~smith/home.html
http://EXAMPLE.com/%7Esmith/home.html
http://EXAMPLE.COM/%7esmith/home.html
```

all represent the same target resource.

I want the facility to translate a URL to a canonical form...

- case of the hostname to be consistent
- support for URLs which are not a complete tuple of scheme, username, password, port, path, query and fragment
- handle implicit port and explicit port number sensibly
- the resulting URL ascii encoded with expansion of %.... sequences where appropriate
- handles './' and '../' in paths sensibly
- optionally sorting the variables in the query consistently

Is there an easy way to do this consistently?

(It appears that `parse_url()` does none of these.)

Comment: So..... you want all four of the above examples to be combined down to a single Cannonical URI because they all infact point to an identical loction?

Comment: Given the semantics of the term "canonical" in relation to HTTP it perhaps confuses things somewhat - but yes - I want to normalize them.

Comment: It's not difficult, it's simply tedious. Use `parse_url` to break the URL into parts, use `strtolower` to compare domain names (or a case insensitive matching function), use a harcode check that if no port given the port`80` or `443` is implied, use `url_decode` to normalise comparisons... etc. etc.

Comment: By the way, URLs are not necessarily case sensitive. Maybe in practice the host part is but there's no rule to require that to be the case

Comment: @apokryfos only domain names are not case sensitive. Apache for instance is case aware `/thisIs.html` is not `/ThisIs.html` in many cases.

Comment: @apokryfos: the host (at least if it is a DNS name) and the scheme are the *only* parts of a URL which are case insensitive.

Comment: @symcbean I'm now thinking of the implications of that when using URL encoded non-ASCII characters for hostnames (which is probably allowed e.g. for i18n purposes) and my brain is kind of falling apart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [glenscott/url-normalizer](https://github.com/glenscott/url-normalizer) package for URL normalization in compliance of the specification RFC 3986. You can see the result of normalization with help the following simple example:

```
$urls = [
    'http://example.com/~smith/home.html',
    'http://example.com:80/~smith/home.html',
    'http://EXAMPLE.com/%7Esmith/home.html',
    'http://EXAMPLE.COM/%7esmith/home.html',
    'https://example.com:443/~smith/home.html'
];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $normalizer = new URL\Normalizer($url);
    echo $normalizer->normalize(), "</br>"; 
}
```

The result:

> [http://example.com/~smith/home.html](http://example.com/%7Esmith/home.html)
>
> [http://example.com/~smith/home.html](http://example.com/%7Esmith/home.html)
>
> [http://example.com/~smith/home.html](http://example.com/%7Esmith/home.html)
>
> [http://example.com/~smith/home.html](http://example.com/%7Esmith/home.html)
>
> [https://example.com/~smith/home.html](https://example.com/%7Esmith/home.html)

Comment: nothing, 443 it's not http. so in this case it need to have another url

Comment: @Martin, No. You should use https scheme... For example: `http://example.com:443/~smith/home.html` - won't normalize to https, but `https://example.com:443/~smith/home.html` will be normalized

Comment: @Martin 443 is default port for HTTPS, but it's port number only. It doesn't tell about HTTPS usage anything. For example, you can use 443 port as the port of HTTP instead of the default port. Therefore you should use HTTPS scheme

Comment: @MaximFedorov the same can be said for port 80. *shrug*.

Comment: Package looks pretty cool and states the other requirement: _Sort query parameters. Enabling this option sorts the query parameters by key alphabetically._

Comment: @Martin Yes, of course. Therefore normalization might remove only default number port for a used scheme.